# How to drag an indivudual texture in libgdx android

Tags: android, libgdx

I have two textures drawn in my 2d scene. And I want to drag them each separately. When they are touched and dragged I want both textures to be dragged to each points. How it drag them individually, or is there any other method to implement. as I am a beginner to libgdx.

My code:

```
public class MyGdxGame implements ApplicationListener{
OrthographicCamera camera;
ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
float screenOffset=10,circleRadius=30;


Texture firstTexture;
Texture secondTexture;

float firstTextureX;
float firstTextureY;
float secondTextureX;
float secondTextureY;

float touchX;
float touchY;
SpriteBatch batch;
@Override
public void create()
{
    firstTexture= new Texture("b1.jpg");
    firstTextureX = 50;
    firstTextureY = 50;

    secondTexture = new Texture("b2.jpg");
    secondTextureX = 250;
    secondTextureY = 250;

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    camera=new OrthographicCamera();
    shapeRenderer=new ShapeRenderer();
    shapeRenderer.setAutoShapeType(true);


}

@Override
public void render()
{
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    shapeRenderer.begin();
    shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
    shapeRenderer.circle(camera.viewportWidth/2,camera.viewportHeight/2,circleRadius);
    shapeRenderer.rect(screenOffset,screenOffset,camera.viewportWidth-2*screenOffset,camera.viewportHeight-2*screenOffset);
    shapeRenderer.line(screenOffset,screenOffset,camera.viewportWidth-screenOffset,camera.viewportHeight-screenOffset);
    shapeRenderer.line(screenOffset,camera.viewportHeight-screenOffset,camera.viewportWidth-screenOffset,screenOffset);
    shapeRenderer.line(screenOffset,camera.viewportHeight/2,camera.viewportWidth-screenOffset,camera.viewportHeight/2);
    shapeRenderer.line(camera.viewportWidth/2,screenOffset,camera.viewportWidth/2,camera.viewportHeight-screenOffset);

    shapeRenderer.end();


    batch.begin(); 


    batch.draw(firstTexture, firstTextureX, firstTextureY);
    batch.draw(secondTexture, secondTextureX, secondTextureY);

        batch.end();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should save the current position of the texture, and on the **update**, move the texture checking the movement of the mouse if the mouse right click is active. This is the general idea, valid for any framework or code.

I recommend you to move the texture to their own class, with a getter and a setter of the position and the texture, so it's easy to manage.

Using libdgx you can check if the mouse is clicked at any time with

```
Gdx.input.justTouched();
```

On every update you can check what was the last position of the mouse and calculate the difference with the new position on every update using

```
Gdx.input.getX()
Gdx.input.getY()
```

To syncronize the position inside your screen with the position on your camera you should use unproject on your camera, for example:

```
Vector3 mousePos = new Vector3();
mousePos.x = Gdx.input.getX();
mousePos.y = Gdx.input.getY();
mousePos.z = 0;

camera.unproject(mousePos); //this will convert the screen position to your camera position
```

TL;DR you need to check what was the last position of the mouse when it was clicked, and on the next update calculate the difference, and then you update the position of the texture.

---

BTW, although this is for **when you get more experience**, you can create a class that implements InputProcessor, alow the class to be processed by libgdx with, for example:

```
public class CameraControllerDesktop implements InputProcessor, ControllerListener {

    public CameraControllerDesktop() {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }
```

and the you could use the function

```
@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
return false;
}
```

to let libgx calculate the position of what you are dragging.

---

Sorry about not writing the entire solution, but if whit this info you can solve your problem, I'm pretty sure that you sooner or later will be able to make the game you want.